# If $f$ is continuous, $f'$ exists except at most in a countably infinite set and $f'$ increasing, then $f$ is convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Assume that $f:(a,b) \to R$ is a convex function. We know that $f$ is continuous, $f'$ exists except at most in a countably infinite set and $f'$ is increasing.

What about the viceversa? If $f$ is continuous, $f'$ exists except at most in a countably infinite set and $f'$ is increasing, then $f$ is convex?

Comment: Consider $F(x) := f(a) + \int_a^x f'(t) \lambda^1(dt)$. Then $f = F$ and $F$ is convex.